# How do I open an inferior Python process in a full window from the command line?

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

From the command line, I want to open an inferior Python process in a full window. I have tried: `emacs --eval '(run-python)'`, but when Emacs opens, the `*scratch*` buffer is shown instead of the inferior Python process buffer. The Python process is started, but it is not the focused buffer. From the command line, how do I focus the inferior Python process in a full window when starting Emacs?

Assume that I am using GNU Emacs 26.3 with no custom configuration (i.e. `emacs --no-site-file --no-init-file ...`).

Comment: Things within the `.emacs` / `init.el`, if any, can affect what is displayed at startup.  The last hook to be called during startup (that is related to startup) is the `emacs-startup-hook`:  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Standard-Hooks.html  One idea would be to add your function to that hook and see if that does the trick.  Other things to try are using `switch-to-buffer` or `set-window-buffer`, and if there are too many windows displayed, then `delete-other-windows`.  The `startup.el` cannot be modified once Emacs has been built from source; i.e., it's baked-in.

Comment: @lawlist Assume that I have no custom configuration (i.e. `emacs --no-site-file --no-init-file ...`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution:

```
emacs --eval '(progn (pop-to-buffer (process-buffer (run-python))) (delete-other-windows))'
```

This starts an inferior Python process, focuses it, and makes it take up the whole frame.